# Building separate theme for separate urls for Readthedocs

Tags: github, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm looking for a solution that would allow us to have separate themes in the built docs through rtd, based on urls. The project is github-hosted, so we're using the Webhook integration there for rtd.

Basically, we'd like to have *slug*.readthedocs.io use a default, and have a custom domain through rtd, i.e. docs.ourdomain.org, use a theme styled to match our site.

`on_rtd`, it seems, is `True` whenever rtd builds the docs, so that's likely not useful, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Perhaps multiple Webhooks? Some `sphinx` magic I haven't discovered yet?

Considering using branches or tags, but that just seems a bit much, and would, I believe, call for multiple project-naming on rtd. Though, again, please correct me if I'm wrong.

At the moment, we've implemented our site theming, and simply let that be in place for both, but ideally, we hope to have the *slug*.readthedocs.io site be more generic and in-line with the readthedocs.io feel.

Comment: rtd does not support multiple themes per repo. You will need to clone it or fork it, and keep it in sync.

Comment: I'm under the impression it does, via branches or tags at least. Is this not correct?

Comment: Also, it seems we could implement sub projects under a to level doc project, with separate themes for subprojects. Am I wrong in that, as well?

Comment: Ah, yes, a branch should function the same as a fork on rtd. I think subprojects are separate projects or repos under a parent organization, or that's how we use that feature.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @StevePiercy. We've got some thinking to do. (Side note: Thanks for your work on Pyramid. I'm a fan.)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) doesn't support multiple themes for a given repo/branch.

There are at least a couple of approaches available here.

1) Use branches to host alternative docs. Read The Docs has an example project illustrating this approach here:

- [Read the Docs Sphinx Theme Examples](https://rtd-sphinx-theme-sample-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
  -- [[Github Repository](https://github.com/rtfd/rtd-sphinx-themes-examples)]

2) Use [sub-projects](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/subprojects.html).

Neither of these really addresses the use case in my question *directly*, but they do offer a sort alternative approach to multiple themes.